# Simple Grid Not Working Chakra-ui although tried different method

Tags: reactjs, api, grid, chakra-ui

My Simple Grid is not Working I wanted to have items in a straight line but the items are horizontally there[image]

MY CODE
PLEASE NOTE THAT APPLYING WIDTH TO SIMPLE GRID ALSO RENDER THE SAME SO NO MATTER I APPLY W TO IT OR NOT

```js
                        <SimpleGrid w={"90vw"} column={2} spacing={10}>
                            {result.data.map((e) => {

                                return (
                                    <Box w={"20vw"} key={e.id}>

                                        < Item title={e.title.slice(0, 25) + "..."} src={e.images.original.mp4} />
                                    </Box>

                                )

                            })}
                        </SimpleGrid>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You made a spelling mistake. It is `columns` not `column`

```
<SimpleGrid w={"90vw"} columns={2} spacing={10}>
   {result.data.map((e) => {
      return (
        <Box w={"20vw"} key={e.id}>
           <Item title={e.title.slice(0, 25) + "..."} src={e.images.original.mp4} />
        </Box>

       )

    })}
</SimpleGrid>
```